# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match." - but they do

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to integrate an ML model into an Android app with the following code in Android Studio:

```
predictBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    ModelUnquant model = ModelUnquant.newInstance(MainActivity.this);


                    // Check if bitmap is not null
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        // Creates inputs for reference.
                        TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 244, 244, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);

                        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 244, 244, true);
                        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap).getBuffer());

                        // Runs model inference and gets result.
                        ModelUnquant.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
                        TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

                        // Change class number here
                        result.setText(labels[getMax(outputFeature0.getFloatArray())]+" ");
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case when bitmap is null
                        result.setText("Error: No Image");
                    }

                    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                    model.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Handle the exception
                }
            }
        });
```

Which returns the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.archeyewitness, PID: 15698

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.

at org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.SupportPreconditions.checkArgument(SupportPreconditions.java:104)

at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:309)

at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:328)

at com.example.archeyewitness.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:96)
```

Now, I've tried to debug this by printing the sizes of the byte buffer and the shape:

```
Log.d("DebugInfo", "Tensor Buffer Size: " + tensorBufferSize);
Log.d("DebugInfo", "Byte Buffer Size: " + byteBufferSize);
Log.d("DebugInfo", "Tensor Buffer Shape: " + Arrays.toString(tensorBufferShape));
Log.d("DebugInfo", "Expected Shape: " + Arrays.toString(byteBufferShape));
```

That returns the following:

```
Tensor Buffer Size: 150528
2024-01-25 18:29:33.965 14367-14367 DebugInfo               com.example.archeyewitness           D  Byte Buffer Size: 150528
2024-01-25 18:29:33.965 14367-14367 DebugInfo               com.example.archeyewitness           D  Tensor Buffer Shape: [1, 224, 224, 3]
2024-01-25 18:29:33.965 14367-14367 DebugInfo               com.example.archeyewitness           D  Expected Shape: [1, 224, 224, 3]
2024-01-25 18:29:33.971 14367-14367 AndroidRuntime          com.example.archeyewitness           D  Shutting down VM
2024-01-25 18:29:33.992 14367-14367 AndroidRuntime          com.example.archeyewitness
```

As you can see, the sizes do match, but I still get the same error. Can someone explain what's going on?